# At what point are request and response objects populated in express app

Tags: node.js, express

I’m always coding backend api’s and I don’t really get how express does its bidding with my code. I know what the request and response objects offer, I just don’t understand how they come to be.

This simplified code for instance:

```
exports.getBlurts = function() {
    return function(req, res) { 

    // build query…

    qry.exec(function(err, results) {
            res.json(results);
        }
    });
  } 
}
```

Then I’d call in one of my routes:

```
app.get('/getblurts/, middleware.requireUser, routes.api.blurtapi.getBlurts());
```

I get that the function is called upon the route request. It’s very abstract to me though and I don’t understand the when, where, or how as it pertains to the req\res params being injected.

For instance. I use a CMS that modifies the request object by adding a user property, which is then available globally on all requests made whether ajax or otherwise, making it easy at all times to determine if a user is logged in.

Are the req and res objects just pre-cooked by express but allow freedom for them to be modified to your needs? When are they actually 'built'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its heart express is actually using node's default http-module and passing the express-application as a callback to the `http.createServer`-function. The request and response objects are populated at that point, i.e. from node itself for every incoming connection. See [the nodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) for more details regarding node's http-module and what req/res are.

You might want to check out [express' source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L617) which shows how the express application is passed as a callback to `http.createServer`.

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/request.js and https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js show how node's request/response are extended by express specific functions.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Especially with the two github branches, that code really brings it home in certain respects. However, is there any best practices for where/when to modify the request object? For instance, adding a property like a mentioned in my question.

Comment: Good question. In our last project we've used a custom middleware to add a `requestMetadata` object to the req-object which was executed right after the default middleware (like cors and body-parser). This metadata object contained data from e.g. the access-token which then could be used in our routers and/or other middlewares. Not sure if that's the way to go, maybe someone else also has some input or ideas :)

Comment: I was thinking about posing this as a question, but the more I think about it and tinker around, the more I realize that your answer is really the only viable one. So I think you pretty much hit it on the head with the middleware suggestion, adding some sort of metadata properties. Thanks!